# While looping sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, random, while-loop

I am trying to update all of the rows in a table in my database with a different value.  I am trying to while loop the query to do this.  Here's what I have...

```
<?php
$rand = rand(100,150000);
$start = 1;
$start += $start;
$start2 = $start +1;
echo $start;
while($start =< 686) {
echo "UPDATE table_video SET total_view = $rand WHERE id BETWEEN $start AND $start2;";
};
?>
```

I am sure most of you should be able to look at my code and understand what I am trying to accomplish.  I would like the assistance.  Thank You very much!

Comment: You only echo the query, never execute.. `$rand` also will only be generated once. All records will have the same integer on each iteration. You should put the assignment in the loop.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the `$start` thing... you initialise it to `1`. Then you add `1` (`$start = 2`) and then `$start2` is `$start + 1` which is `3`. (I don't know why you do all of that tbh. Then you make a `while-statement` that never ends because you're never increasing the `$start` (so it always is `$start =< 686`).

Comment: why you use a LOOP? instead just update all the columns with a random value?

Comment: What I want is for the first instance to echo `UPDATE table_video SET total_view = 74956 WHERE id = 1;` then `UPDATE table_video SET total_view = 54687 WHERE id = 2;` ... I made a mistake in my question, the BETWEEN was for a different trial and error.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza how would I do that?

Comment: In case there's any confusion why I am echoing out the statements instead of updating the rows in php is because I am using a third-party script and don't want to mess it up.  So I planned on copying the results of this code directly into PHPMyAdmin

Comment: the `rand()` value is just calculated once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mySQL [**RAND()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) function,  min and max your range for the random values. I belive on this case are `(100,150000)`

```
UPDATE table_video 
SET total_view =  ROUND( (RAND() * (max-min)) +min )
WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 686;
```

Comment: That worked.  Thank You very much @JuanCarlosOropeza